# Rational Test Workbench if condition

Tags: testing, ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I am trying to do mobile testing with IBM Rational Test Workbench. And the problem is, that when I open the app, it opens different pages every time (its a part of a normal workflow). I recorded all the steps that might occur, but I can't find out how to invoke them differently depending on verification point (something like if/else block).

**For Example:** if mainpage opens proceed with steps 2 and 3 and if page2 opens proceed with steps 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment (up to 8702)

In next version (871, should be live Mid October, 2015), some specific kind of test element (Responsive Design Condition) have been added to offer a solution for the most usual case (app that show special part, as demo layout or credential asking on first execution).

this special test element will only be available for android version

Jerome Bozier

Senior Software Engineer, RTW Mobile Android, IBM